# Inconsistent answers to simple queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I receive results that I consider inconsistent to simple queries.

```
-- This returns 3 rows
select * from persons
where person_id in (12,13,14)

-- This returns nothing
select *
from documents 
where person_id in (12,13,14)

-- This returns nothing !?!?
select *
  from persons
 where persons.person_id not in ( select documents.person_id from documents )
```

There is a FK on documents.person_id pointing to persons.person_id

Am I missing something?
This is my @@version:

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU1) (KB3208177) - 13.0.4411.0 (X64)   Jan  6 2017 14:24:37   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: ( select documents.person_id from documents where person_id IS NOT NULL)

Comment: ok, that was the best case scenario, I missed something stupid   :-)
do you want to make an answer out of it so that I accept?

Comment: @carlo.borreo - Have a look at [SQL Server Three-Valued Logic and NOT IN clause with NULL values](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/57894/sql-server-three-valued-logic-not-clause-null-values/)

Comment: What returns `select documents.person_id from documents`?

Comment: Yes this post is rightly duplicate.Just using EXISTS clause will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Scott Hodgin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/60085/scott-hodgin) has pointed out on his comments there is some NULL value for person_id in the `documents` table.

You can easily avoid it by adding `where person_id is not null`

> ```
> create table persons (personID int);
> create table documents (documentID int, personID int);
>
> insert into persons values(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15);
> insert into documents values (1,10),(1,11),(1,null),(2,null),(3,11),(3,15);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 12 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from persons where personID in (12,13,14);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | personID |
> | -------: |
> |       12 |
> |       13 |
> |       14 |
> ```

> ```
> select * from documents where personID in (12,13,14);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> documentID | personID
> ---------: | -------:
> ```

> ```
> select personID from documents
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | personID |
> | -------: |
> |       10 |
> |       11 |
> |     null |
> |     null |
> |       11 |
> |       15 |
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from   persons
> where  personID not in (select personID from documents);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | personID |
> | -------: |
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from   persons
> where  personID not in (select personID from documents where personID is not null);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | personID |
> | -------: |
> |       12 |
> |       13 |
> |       14 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=944dcff223bfb1770175f3b0567d1657)*